# How to stop child element click in angular 5?

Tags: javascript, angular

I referred so many references, but not getting any responses. Thats y i came here to develop my code through yours.

Have to append the element with the text on click. It works and appends inside the ul element as li element with text. But i want to disable or stop the child event. Since i wrote the onclick on parent element only. It should not be click able on the child element. Please help on this.

Sharing the url :

- [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hostbinding-decorator](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-61eytr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: did u check event.stopPropagation() ?

Comment: Yes i check with event.stoppropagarion

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're using a renderer instead of a classic `*ngFor` ?

Comment: An Angular-style working solution for doing what you want is : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8bem8n

Comment: Nice. Its good when deal with array. thanks @YoukouleleY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have studied your code and found the problem. The `ul` is the parent element and must be referenced by `abcd` and the click handler on first `li` that is responsible for adding child receives the event.

```
<div hostbinding color="white">{{name}}</div>
<h1>Hello {{thingTwo}}</h1>
<ul #abcd>
   <li (click) = "dasdas($event)" >Click here to add li</li>
</ul>
```